# Java: Protobuf byte to Json string to Pojo fast

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

I am receiving messages in protobuf format. I need to convert it to json format **fast** as all my business logic is written to handle json based POJO objects.

```
byte[] request = ..; // msg received

// convert to intermediate POJO
AdxOpenRtb.BidRequest bidRequestProto = AdxOpenRtb.BidRequest.parseFrom(request, reg);

// convert intermediate POJO to json string.
// THIS STEP IS VERY SLOW
Printer printer = JsonFormat.printer().printingEnumsAsInts().omittingInsignificantWhitespace();
String jsonBody = printer.print(bidRequestProto);

// convert json string to final POJO format
BidRequest bidRequest = super.parse(jsonBody.getBytes());
```

Proto object to json conversion step is very slow. Is there any faster approach for it?

can i reuse `printer` object? is it thread-safe?

**Note:** This POJO class (`AdxOpenRtb.BidRequest` & `BidRequest`) is very complex having many hierarchy and fields but **contains similar data with slightly different fields name and data types**.

Comment: Hand write some code to translate from one POJO to the other. (I assume you don't create a `Printer` for each object)

Comment: @tgdavies I am creating `Printer` for each object. can i resue it? (i didn't find any doc that says so). `Printer printer = JsonFormat.printer().printingEnumsAsInts().omittingInsignificantWhitespace();`. this is used by multiple threads. is it thread-safe?

Comment: I don't know whether it's thread-safe. I would guess that it is.

Comment: Don't just copyu from one pojo to another. Don't do an intermediate step for JSON that will only take resources. Use something like MapStruct to generate mappers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using `MapStruct` as suggested by some of you (@M.Deinum).

new code:

```
byte[] request = ..; // msg received

// convert to intermediate POJO
AdxOpenRtb.BidRequest bidRequestProto = AdxOpenRtb.BidRequest.parseFrom(request, reg);

// direct conversion from protobuf Pojo to my custom Pojo
BidRequest bidRequest = BidRequestMapper.INSTANCE.adxOpenRtbToBidRequest(bidRequestProto);
```

Code snippet of `BidRequestMapper`:

```
@Mapper(
    collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED, nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS,
    unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN)
@DecoratedWith(BidRequestMapperDecorator.class)
public abstract class BidRequestMapper {

  public static final BidRequestMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BidRequestMapper.class);

  @Mapping(source = "impList", target = "imp")
  @Mapping(target = "impOverride", ignore = true)
  @Mapping(target = "ext", ignore = true)
  public abstract BidRequest adxOpenRtbToBidRequest(AdxOpenRtb.BidRequest adxOpenRtb);
...
...
}

// manage proto extensions
abstract class BidRequestMapperDecorator extends BidRequestMapper {
  private final BidRequestMapper delegate;

  BidRequestMapperDecorator(BidRequestMapper delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public BidRequest adxOpenRtbToBidRequest(AdxOpenRtb.BidRequest bidRequestProto) {
    // Covert protobuf msg to basic bid request object
    BidRequest bidRequest = delegate.adxOpenRtbToBidRequest(bidRequestProto);
...
...
  }
}
```

The new approach is **20-50x faster** in my local test environment.

It's worth mentioning that `MapStruct` is an **annotation processor** which makes it much faster than other similar libraries which use **reflection** and it also has very good support for customization.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into some performance issues as well and ended up writing the [QuickBuffers](https://github.com/HebiRobotics/QuickBuffers) library. It generates dedicated JSON serialization methods (i.e. no reflection) and should give you a 10-30x speedup. It can be used side-by-side with Google's implementation. The code should look something like this:

```
    // Initialization (objects can be reused if desired)
    AdxOpenRtb.BidRequest bidRequestProto = AdxOpenRtb.BidRequest.newInstance();
    ProtoSource protoSource = ProtoSource.newArraySource();
    JsonSink jsonSink = JsonSink.newInstance().setWriteEnumsAsInts(true);

    // Convert Protobuf to JSON
    bidRequestProto.clearQuick() // or ::parseFrom if you want a new object
            .mergeFrom(protoSource.setInput(request))
            .writeTo(jsonSink.clear());

    // Use the raw json bytes
    RepeatedByte jsonBytes = jsonSink.getBytes();
```

[JsonSinkBenchmark](https://github.com/HebiRobotics/QuickBuffers/blob/490622c418a630be5d5de2a87c14bdc081684fe9/benchmarks/src/main/java/us/hebi/quickbuf/benchmarks/json/JsonSinkBenchmark.java) has some sample code for replacing the built-in JSON encoder with more battle-tested Gson/Jackson backends.

**Edit**: if you're doing this within a single process and are worried about performance, you're better off writing or generating code to convert the Java objects directly. JSON is not a very efficient format to go through.

Comment: I tried using QuickBuffers but not able to generate files: https://github.com/HebiRobotics/QuickBuffers/issues/35

Comment: Types are currently allocated eagerly to avoid steady state allocations, so it can't be used with recursive message definitions like Struct. I'm considering adding a flag for lazy allocation in the future, but it looks like you are not using that message anyways.